# Unable to filter data in Redux Reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to create a reducer for a ToDo App where i have successfully managed to create an Add reducer but somehow i'm unable to filter data on the basis of the ID suppose my ID is 1 then if there is a ToDo Bucket(bucket is basically a parent where i'm creating ToDo's) then get that ToDo bucket data.

In Redux dev tools i have checked it is showing me a infinite hierarchical tree of **filteredData** object. but not showing directly the Bucket ID 1 data and same with delete reducer as well. Can someone please help in highlighting what exactly wrong i'm doing or missing.

```
 case EDIT_TODO_BUCKET: {
        return (
            {
                ...state,
                data: {
                    ...state.data,
                    [action.payload.id]: {
                        ...state.data[action.payload.id],
                        filteredData: state.data[action.payload.id]
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }

    case DELETE_TODO_BUCKET: {
        return (
            {
                ...state,
                data: {
                    ...state.data,
                    [action.payload.id]: {
                        ...state.data[action.payload.id],
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    case DELETE_TODO_BUCKET: {
        return (
            {
                ...state,
                data: {
                    ...state.data,
                    [action.payload.id]: {
                        ...state.data[action.payload.id],
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

^ Read this It doesn't do anything at all except create a new reference each time.

I imagine you might want the following:

```js
  return {
     ...state,
     // removes the key of action.payload.id from the state.data
     data: Object.entries((acc,[key,value]) => key === action.payload.id ? acc : ({...acc,[key]:value}),{})
  }
```